# Python Logging module formatter

Tags: python, logging, formatter

Having a hard time understanding the formatter options.  specifically the string replacements.  If I have a really long python file name, how do I get it to cut it off to keep everything even?

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-15s %(threadName)-10s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
```

while I understand that I can make the -15s part longer to give me more space between, how do I get it to cut off a long filename say 'this_is_a_test_ok.py' rather than just padding everything out?  I want my final output to be very columnar.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you: You want to print only the first `n` characters of a string of length `m` with `m > n`, right? For `n = 4` and the string `abcde`, you would expect `abcd` to be printed in this case.

Comment: correct that is what I would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested it:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-15.5s %(threadName)-10s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
```

Truncates the loggers's name to 5 chars. How to combine that with padding is another question.

Comment: Got the padding, too. I can add it to the answer, if you do not want to fiddle for yourself.

Comment: I would love to see the padding handled as well. I couldn't do that :/

Comment: Sorry to not post the solution for combining padding and truncating, but otherwise you'd maybe miss [this](https://pyformat.info/) excellent cheatsheet for best-practices in string-formatting. It's got a section for that specific problem. I wish the author could be a paid author for the official python documentation department.

Comment: Bah, I was so close! Thank you very much for the link, it's going to be used a lot :)

Comment: Ok. I've changed the answer. My comment maybe wasn't very thoughtful and I missed the sprit of SO. But regardless of that be sure to bookmark the mentioned site.